# WinSCP AddRawSettings FSProtocol

Tags: c#, .net, winscp, winscp-net

When generating the C# code from the WinSCP GUI, I get

```
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("FSProtocol", "2");
```

Does anyone know what this `FSProtocol` setting and the value `"2"` means?
I tried to google *"FSProtocol"* but fail to get any result specific to it.

Here's a setting list I found from their doc https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings

Answer (score 4):

As @Jason correctly answered, `FSProtocol` specifies the protocol to use. But in WinSCP .NET assembly that is already specified by [`SessionOptions.Protocol` property](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#protocol). So this does not explain, why the `FSProtocol` is needed in your generated code.

The only case out of the protocol list that cannot be covered by `SessionOptions.Protocol` is the `2`, what is SFTP protocol with fallback to SCP disabled. WinSCP by default falls back to SCP protocol, in case the server does not support SFTP. You must have [disabled the fallback in GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp). So the GUI needed to use `FSProtocol` to reflect that non-default settings.

Unless you really wanted the fallback disabled, you can safely remove your `SessionOptions.AddRawSettings` call.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, this makes sense. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

WinSCP helpfully has source code in GitHub (and other places too) - a search in that repo for `FSProtocol` found this line, which nicely lists the names associated with each value - they seem to refer to the different file transfer modes of WinSCP:

https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/c472858e482cbdee0508c64203bc58340b645007/source/core/SessionData.cpp#L48

```
0: SCP
1: SFTP (SCP) 
2: SFTP
3: ???
4: ???
5: FTP
6: WebDAV
7: S3
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason. This helps.